# GoogleMaps API v2 setMyLocationEnabled is different from LocationManager

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am having probably simple question, but i can't figure out, what is wrong.

When i set my location with button on the map, the location is almost 100 exact.

When i use Location manager to get my location, i am getting about 10-20 meters wrong location.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    Button setLoc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setLoc);

    assert setLoc != null;
    setLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mGoogleMap.clear();
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

            latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(latLng), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //zoom to current position:
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Your location").anchor(0.0f, 1.0f));

        }
    });

}
```

What am i doing wrong? The blue point is not at the same place where my marker is, and the blue point have better precision as i said above.
Thanks!

**small UPDATE**
when i run the code on emulator, it is almost the same location...hmm, on real device it is different. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it maybe device dependent. You need to change the priority to `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`. Before requesting location updates, your app must connect to the location services and make a location request. Once a a location request is in place you can start the regular updates by calling [`requestLocationUpdates()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#public-methods) do this in the  [`onConnected()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks#public-methods) callback provided by Google API Client, which is called when the client is ready.

Update location using LocationListener callback. Call `requestLocationUpdates()`, passing it your instance of the GoogleApiClient, the LocationRequest object, and a LocationListener. Define a `startLocationUpdates()` method, called from the `onConnected()` callback.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
...
if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
startLocationUpdates();
}
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

Comment: It worked, i just had to use the **Fused location provider**, the same the blue dot is using. Now my location is always the same. Answer accepted.